# How do I pick a word out of a string without using the split method?

Tags: python

I have a string that looks like this "ABC DEF GHI" and I want to be able to create a new string with only "ABC" or "DEF" or "GHI". I'm trying to use the .isalpha method to determine when the string turns from alphabetic letter to spaces. This is what my code looks like:

```
def get_word(chars: str, width: int) -> str:    
    word = ""
    for i in range(len(chars)):
        if chars[i].isaplpha():
            word += chars[i]
            if chars[i].isspace():
                break
    return word
```

however, I get an unresolved attribute reference error because my input needs to be a string. What does this mean? It is not letting me use the .isalpha. But if i = 1 then chars[i] = "B" which is alphabetic so I'm confused.

I'm not allowed to use the split method... please help!

Comment: You have `isaplpha()` in the code you posted, not `isalpha()`...

Comment: When providing a code sample, include the invocation of the code (a call to `get_word`, in your case). When mentioning an error, provide the full error stack trace you received.

Comment: See https://repl.it/repls/VagueRaggedTrust

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a general solution to this problem, you can use regex:

```
import re

a = "ABC DEF GHI"

output = re.findall('[A-Z]{3}', a)

print(f"""
        First item: {output[0]}
        Second item: {output[1]}
        Third item: {output[2]}
       """)
```

This will retrieve all instances of 3 consecutive capitalized alpha characters (A through Z).

If the input string can also include numbers, like "AB3 DEF 2HI", then you can alternatively use `output = re.findall('\w{3}', a)`.

If the input string has "words" of varying lengths, you can use `output = re.findall('\w+', a)` which will match any number of consecutive characters.

To learn more about regex, and play around with it yourself, you can use [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/)

Answer (score 0):

For this type of problem, you probably want a regular expression

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

```
import re
input =  "ABC DEF GHI"

re.split(r'\s+')  # split on whitespace
>>> ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']

re.match(r'\w+', input)  # get first word
>>> <re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='ABC'>

re.findall(r'\w+', input)  # find all groups of 1+ alphanumeric "word" chars
>>> ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']

re.sub(r'\b\s+\b', '-', input)      # replace all spaces between words with '-'
>>> 'ABC-DEF-GHI'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.partition()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) or [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) within a recursion like these examples:

**Using `str.partition()`:**

```
def split1(string, delim=' '):
    first, sep, rest = string.partition(delim)
    return (
        [first] if first else []
    ) + split(rest, delim) if sep else ([first] if first else [])
```

**Using `str.find()`:**

```
def split2(string, sep=' '): 
     if not sep: 
         raise ValueError('separator length must be >= 1') 
     index = string.find(sep) 
     if index < 0: 
         return [string] if string else [] 
     if len(sep) > 1: 
         index =  len(sep) if not index else index 
         first, rest = string[:index], string[index:] 
     else: 
         first, rest = string[:index], string[index + 1:] 
     return ([first] if first != sep else []) + split2(rest, sep)
```

Tests:

```
word = 'ABC DEF GHI'
seps = [' ', 'DEF', 'ABC', 'GHI', 'C ']
for sep in seps:
    print(split1(word, sep), split2(word, sep))
```

Output:

```
['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'] ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']
['ABC ', ' GHI'] ['ABC ', ' GHI']
[' DEF GHI'] [' DEF GHI']
['ABC DEF ', ''] ['ABC DEF ']
['AB', 'DEF GHI'] ['AB', 'DEF GHI']
```

**Performance comparaison:**

```
%timeit split1(word)
690 ns ± 4.56 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit split2(word)
1.18 µs ± 34.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```